# About the Bridge pattern again

Tags: design-patterns, bridge

I'm trying to understand the Bridge pattern. With examples from Wiki all is ok.
But what if we have the next design:

[image]

How can I implement different remote controls (e.g. Infra-red and Wi-Fi)? Should I use Bridge pattern and how to do it? By analogy with an examples I need to combine all methods to the single wide interface with hardware implementation like on the next figure. But I don't think it's a good idea.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bridge pattern is a lot like the adapter pattern.

Following your model, let's suppose you have an `RemoteControl` abstract class:

```
public abstract class RemoteControl
{
      protected HadwareRemoteControl hardwareBridge;

      //Can be injected using DI
      public RemoteControl(HadwareRemoteControl hardwareBridge)
      {
           this.hardwareBridge= hardwareBridge;
      }

      public void on()
      {
           hardwareBridge.on();
      }

      public void off()
      {
           hardwareBridge.off();
      }
}
```

And two implementations for that class:

```
public class TVRemoteControl extends RemoteControl
{
      public TVRemoteControl(TVHardwareRemoteControl hardwareBridge) {
           super(hardwareBridge);
      }

      public void nextChannel() {
           ((TVHardwareRemoteControl)hardwareBridge).nextChannel();
      }

      public void previousChannel() {
           ((TVHardwareRemoteControl)hardwareBridge).previousChannel();
      }
}

public class ModelRemoteControl extends RemoteControl
{
      public ModelRemoteControl (ModelHardwareRemoteControl hardwareBridge) {
           super(hardwareBridge);
      }

      public void moveForward() {
           ((ModelHardwareRemoteControl)hardwareBridge).moveForward();
      }

      public void moveBack() {
           ((ModelHardwareRemoteControl)hardwareBridge).moveBack();
      }     
}
```

Now, for the hardware bridge, we have a base interface:

```
public interface HadwareRemoteControl
{
      public void on();
      public void off();
}
```

And two more interfaces:

```
public interface TVHadwareRemoteControl extends HardwareRemoteControl
{
      public void nextChannel();
      public void previousChannel();
}

public interface ModelHardwareRemoteControl extends HardwareRemoteControl
{
      public void moveForward();
      public void moveBack();
}
```

And, as in your desing, two implementations:

```
public class InfraredRemoteControl implements TVHardwareRemoteControl, ModelHardwareRemoteControl
{
      public void on()
      {
         //Hardware Turn on
      }

      public void off()
      {
         //Hardware Turn off
      }

      public void nextChannel()
      {
         //Hardware Next channel
      }

      public void previousChannel()
      {
         //Hardware Previous channel
      }

      public void moveForward()
      {
         //Hardware Move Forward
      }

      public void moveBack()
      {
         //Hardware Move Back
      }
}


public class WifiRemoteControl implements TVHardwareRemoteControl, ModelHardwareRemoteControl
{
      public void on()
      {
         //Hardware Turn on
      }

      public void off()
      {
         //Hardware Turn off
      }

      public void nextChannel()
      {
         //Hardware Next channel
      }

      public void previousChannel()
      {
         //Hardware Previous channel
      }

      public void moveForward()
      {
         //Hardware Move Forward
      }

      public void moveBack()
      {
         //Hardware Move Back
      }
}
```

From an external project, a client of your API may use the hardware more transparently, not even aware of these implementations:

```
TVRemoteControl tvRemote = Factory.CreateTVRemote();

//Depending on the injected hardware implementation, it may call InfraredRemoteControl or WifiRemoteControl
tvRemote.on();
tvRemote.nextChannel();
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed response. The main question was related with hardware interface. And you are right, it's better to use three interfaces just like you do. It fits Interface Segregation Principle.